# Docker Compose 3 controlling resources (memory, cpu)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use "resources" field from docker compose version 3 documentation (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/), however, I'm facing an error,

> ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
>   Unsupported config option for services.fstore_java: 'resources'

How can I set the memory limit with docker-compose?

```
  fstore_java:
    depends_on:
      - fstore_db
      - rabbit_broker
    build: ./fstore
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    expose:
      - "8080"
    links:
      - fstore_db
      - rabbit_broker
    restart: always
    resources:
      limits:
        cpus: '0.001'
        memory: 50M
```

Comment: Is that your entire compose file? If so, you missed the process to use the version 3 format.

Comment: Also, what version of docker-compose are you using?

Comment: @BMitch I have version: '3', docker compose 1.11.1, docker 1.13.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be under "deploy" level

```
  fstore_java:
depends_on:
  - fstore_db
  - rabbit_broker
build: ./fstore
ports:
  - "8080:8080"
expose:
  - "8080"
links:
  - fstore_db
  - rabbit_broker
restart: always
deploy:
  resources:
    limits:
      cpus: '0.001'
      memory: 50M
```

Comment: note this only works in swarm mode and docker-compose will ignore this, https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources and https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4513

Comment: As the above poster notes, this fails with `WARNING: Some services use the 'deploy' key, which will be ignored. Compose does not support 'deploy' configuration - use `docker stack deploy` to deploy to a swarm.`